# Given two tangent circles, find the two centers of a third that is tangent to both with given radius

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[Click to see my hand drawn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbGDY.jpg)

Given the center and radius of two circles that are tangent to each other, I need the two possible centers of a third circle with a given radius that is tangent to the first two.

Sorry about the hand-drawn image.  I need $(x_3, y_3)$ in the picture where all three circles touch and I know the radii of all the circles.  I understand there should be two such points.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE: I thought I would share the code I came up with using the accepted answer below.  When I finally worked it all out, the code is surprisingly simple!!! (The variable names are from the image in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349125/circle-circle-intersection-points).  Oh, this is in the Processing language.

```
// Find the center of a third circle tangent to two original tangent
// circles with a given radius.  Works by finding the intersection of
// the two circles centered where the original two are but with radii
// r0+newR and r1+newR.

PVector findThirdCenterOfTangentCircles(
              float x0, float y0, float r0,
              float x1, float y1, float r1,
              float newR){

     float d = dist(x0, y0, x1, y1);
     r0 += newR; // if it wasn't for these two lines we would just be finding the
     r1 += newR; //   intersection of the original two circles
     float a = ((r0*r0)-(r1*r1)+(d*d))/(2*d);
     float h = sqrt((r0*r0)-(a*a));
     float x2 = x0 + a*(x1-x0)/d;
     float y2 = y0 + a*(y1-y0)/d;
     float x3 = x2 + h*(y1-y0)/d;
     float y3 = y2 - h*(x1-x0)/d;
     // other point would be...
     //    float x3 = x2 - h*(y1-y0)/d;
     //    float y3 = y2 + h*(x1-x0)/d;

     return new PVector(x3, y3);
}
```

Comment: The locus of the centers of any circle of given radius $s$ which is is tangent to a fixed circle $A$ or radius $r$ is a circle with center at $A$ and radius $r+s$. If you appy this to two fixed circles, then you need to find the intersection of two circle loci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that the tangency conditions are satisfied if and only if 
$$\begin{cases}(x_3-x_1)^2+(y_3-y_1)^2=(r_1+r_3)^2\\
(x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2=(r_2+r_3)^2
\end{cases}$$
that is the two possible centers of the third circle are determined by intersecting the circles $C_i$ centered at $(x_i,y_i)$ and of radius $r_i+r_3$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: Ok..... I think I see what that is saying.... that the distance calculated between the centers using the given points would be equal to the sum of the radiuses.  Ok... got that......  So..... I'm still lost ;)

Comment: You should solve the non-linear system. Have you the coordinates of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$?

Comment: No I don't... they are randomly generated in my code.  As is r3.

Comment: By subtracting the two equations you will find a linear equation. Find $y_3$ as function of $x_3$ and then substitute  $y_3$  in  one of the the two equations and solve the quadratic equation to find $x_3$.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349125/circle-circle-intersection-points

Comment: Ok I think I am seeing how to work this out.  Will do it later and update with what I figure out.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  I updated the question with my code using what you gave me and it turned out to be surprising simple in the end.

Comment: Very well. I'm glad it helped!